# Build account model using query string MVC

Tags: build, model, query-string, using

I have two MVC websites, I just want to ask if this is possible:

**Website A** is the firts website to load, the user will enter details to it, and then will be redirected to **website B**, but I want to use the value in website A to build a the model in website B using a query string like this:

```
http://websiteb.com/Status?state=South Carolina&zipCode=29418
```

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you haven't really asked a question, and secondly, passing username and password in a query string seems to me to be a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew, but my question is if it is possible to build a model of another website by using just the query string passed by another website. Yes that won't be a good idea but it's just an example, I edited that one for you.